# Django error trying to delete a file using virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

> File
>   "/srv/xxxx/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py",
>   line 193, in delete
>          os.remove(name)
>
> ```
> OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
> ```
>
> '/srv/notxxxelinq/app/xxx/site_media/xx/xxx/20101217T194905.document.pdf'

I've tried chmod +x on django-admin.py but that didn't do the trick. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the permissions on your `site_media` directory might be wrong - what are the permissions on that directory?

Comment: Obvious. Thank you. I just needed to add write permissions for those directories. Thank you!